# Why is the content showing along side with navbar? Why can't it display after navbar?

Tags: html, css, layout, navbar, nav

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOZt9.png)

Hello I am creating a hero section but the info that I am writing is showing in the navbar. I want it to display under the navbar. I can't find the solution. Please help. I am not good at css

```css
* {
  background-color: #171717;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 25%;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

.nav nav {
  float: right;
}

.nav nav .links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav nav .links .link {
  margin: 0 20px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    <nav>
      <ul class="links">
        <li class="link">Home</li>
        <li class="link">Project</li>
        <li class="link">About</li>
        <li class="link">Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container info2">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

I want hello to display beneath the navbar. When I try to give the margin to info2(hello) it affects the navbar too. I don't understand please help.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? Like Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove your CSS class selector `.nav nav { float : right; }`

And in class `.nav nav .links` add `padding: 0; justify-content: right;`

(I removed the `margin` in class `.containr` for example)

```css
* {
  background-color: #171717;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.container {
/*  margin: 0 25%; */
  margin-top: 1%;
}

.nav nav .links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: right;
}

.nav nav .links .link {
  margin: 0 20px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    <nav>
      <ul class="links">
        <li class="link">Home</li>
        <li class="link">Project</li>
        <li class="link">About</li>
        <li class="link">Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container info2">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By changing hello tag place in the code and using flex I think you can do this.

```css
* {
  background-color: #171717;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 25%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav nav {
  float: right;
}

.nav nav .links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav nav .links .link {
  margin: 0 20px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    <nav>
      <ul class="links">
        <li class="link">Home</li>
        <li class="link">Project</li>
        <li class="link">About</li>
        <li class="link">Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
   <div class="container info2">
     <h1>Hello</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the `float: right;` that's causing the problem. Just add `clear:both;` to the div with class info2. See [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) for details. These days developers tend to shy away from using floats. There are much more modern ways of dealing with layouts like [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

```css
* {
  background-color: #171717;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 25%;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

.nav nav {
  float: right;
}

.nav nav .links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav nav .links .link {
  margin: 0 20px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
}

/* added this */
.info2 {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    <nav>
      <ul class="links">
        <li class="link">Home</li>
        <li class="link">Project</li>
        <li class="link">About</li>
        <li class="link">Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container info2">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```